# Formula for Oblique Asymptotes

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics, graphing-functions

The question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77220/655672) elaborates on the common method to find asymptotes—divide and the quotient's your answer. I understand this, and also why it works. However, my book has a rather different definition:

> If the limits
> $$
> \lim_{x\to∞}\frac{f(x)}{x} = k,\ \lim_{x\to∞}\big(f(x) -kx\big) = b
> $$
> exist, then, the straight line $y = kx+b$ is an inclined (right) asymptote

and likewise for the inclined left asymptote as $x\to-∞$. Why is this correct, and where does this come from? Google searches only yield the long division approach, and nothing about this one.

Comment: See: Haghdad S. Memauri and Herman Lee Windham, [*On asymptotes of the graphs of algebraic functions*](https://www.kappamuepsilon.org/Pentagon/Vol_52_Num_2_Spring_1993.pdf), **The Pentagon** 52 #2 (Spring 1993), 39-50.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks! I get it now