# Deriving the formula for oblique asymptotes

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, limits, asymptotics, graphing-functions

In order to find an oblique asymptote, we need to find some function $\phi(x)=kx+n$ or in other words, to find $k$ and $n$. Finding $n$ is pretty straightforward:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(f(x)-\phi(x))&=0 \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(f(x)-kx-n)&=0 \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(f(x)-kx)&=n
\end{align*}
$$
Of course, in order to find $n$, we need $k$ first:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(f(x)-\phi(x))&=0 \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}(f(x)-kx-n)&=0 \ \ \text\ \cdot \frac{1}{x} \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\left( \frac{f(x)}{x}-k-\frac{n}{x} \right)&=0 \\
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\left( \frac{f(x)}{x} \right)&=k
\end{align*}
$$
Where $\frac{n}{x}$ tends towards $0$ and we get the formula for $k$.

**Question: Are we allowed to divide the whole equation by $x$ in the second step, and if not, why?**

I found [other similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77220/the-intuition-behind-slant-asymptotes) and [answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4279358/formula-for-oblique-asymptotes) and another way to derive the formula but my professor showed me this one and was confused about it so I'm just wondering why,what's wrong with it.

Comment: It sounds like your professor showed this to you but you don’t believe it’s correct. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: He was the one that was confused by it and ended up looking at it for 5 minutes before ending the class. I only have a doubt at what may have been confusing him (the division by $x$) but I'm not sure why.